# Restrict SSE instruction set

Tags: gcc, compilation, clang, sse

I want my compiler to use only instructions of the specified version of SSE.

For now, looks like `-msse2 -mno-sse3 -mno-sse4 -mno-sse41 -mno-sse42` does it, however I'm looking for something like `-monly-sse2`.

Comment: is this for gcc? if so can you add the tag, it will attract the right crowd...

Comment: @rene The solution should work with gcc and clang

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify `-msse3`/`-march=<cpu-with-sse3>` only SSE2 will be used on x86-64 (and even lower instruction sets on x86).

Comment: But what if I specify -msse3? How can I tell a compiler to not use newer instructions?

Comment: It will use SSE3, but not SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4A, or any newer exceptions. It will, however, use SSE and SSE2.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I experience. E.g. when I compile python with `-msse3` only, the resulted binary contains SSE4 instructions like `vroundsd`. However, if I disable SSE4 explicitly by appending `-mno-sse4`, the resulting binary does not contain these instructions. My compiler is `Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)`

Comment: @Kentzo Then you're probably overriding it with some other option or manual use of intrinsics. The compiler is not allowed to issue higher instructions than what is specified. The behavior you want is already what the compiler does. If it's still issuing higher instructions, then there's something wrong with either the code or your compiler options.

Comment: I'm pretty sure nothing is wrong with arguments passed to compiler. Here is an example: `-c -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -msse2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Objects/codeobject.o Objects/codeobject.c` The rest mostly look the same.

Comment: It looks like your compiler assumes '-mavx` by default. Check your `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and try to use `-ccc-print-options` flag for `clang` to diagnose the problem.

Comment: So, you think something overrides arguments passed to the compiler (e.g. by modifying some other place where compiler look for arguments)?

Comment: Yes. Normally compiler assumes only the architectural minimum as its target ISA